# React/JS - Creating a conditional on the server response of action call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a modal to add a todo item that resets after submission but it also resets if the submission fails, How do I make it so my modal stays open and user can see the errors they made?

```
//modal component
onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newTask = {
    task: this.state.task
  };
  this.props.addTask(newTask)

  // sudo code below
  if(this.props.addTask(newTask === 200 status success or something){
    this.setState({task: "" })
  //Close modal
    this.toggle();
   }
}

 // action file
export const addTask = (task) => dispatch =>{
  axios.post('/api/users/newtask', task )
      .then(res => 
          dispatch({
              type: ADD_TASK,
              payload: res.data
          })
  ).catch(err =>
      dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
      })
  );
}
```

Not sure if it helps but I'm using axios for the api calls

Comment: I'm assuming `this.props.addTask` is a promise? Can you share that code?

Comment: yes updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways of doing this:

1. A callback that you can pass into your dispatch action:

```
//modal component
onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newTask = {
    task: this.state.task
  };
  this.props.addTask(newTask, () => {
    this.setState({task: "" })
    //Close modal
    this.toggle();
  });
}

 // action file
export const addTask = (task, successCallback) => dispatch =>{
  axios.post('/api/users/newtask', task )
      .then(res => {
          dispatch({
              type: ADD_TASK,
              payload: res.data
          });
          if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
             successCallback(res.data);
          }
        )
  ).catch(err =>
      dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
      })
  );
}
```

2. Ideally, you should be doing this via your redux actions/reducers:

```
//modal component (Or don't render the modal at all at the parent component)
...
render() {
  if (!this.props.showModal) {
    return null;
  }
}

// Action:    
dispatch({
    type: ADD_TASK,
    payload: res.data
});

//Reducer
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TASK:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        tasks: [...state.tasks, action.task],
        showModal: false, // <== Set show modal to false when the task is done.
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: You may also want to store the error in state as well.

Comment: @jaywhy13 He does (In his dispatch action `GET_ERRORS`)

Comment: @FrankerZ hey man i've been trying to solve this problem my solution initially worked but I noticed I have to press submit twice. could you take a look at my gist and help me out real quick? https://gist.github.com/wolffles/aa172da576639e4832ad0017423a30b5

Comment: There should be no `.toggle()` functions anywhere in your code. Your state should be in charge: You change a Boolean showmodal to false: The modal is hidden. Let your state be in charge.

Comment: @frankerZ I'm sorry man I haven't done something like this before, could you show me?